# AntiX Linux how to install Java 8?

Tags: linux, debian, java

I am using the antiX 22 x64 version and I was able to install default Java (Java-11) and Java 17 with

```
$ sudo apt install default-jre
```

and

```
$ sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre
```

But when I try to install Java 8 I get this error:

```
$ sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-8-jre is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
nvidia-openjdk-8-jre

E: Package 'openjdk-8-jre' has no installation candidate
```

Then I install the following package:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-openjdk-8-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-openjdk-8-jre
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 28.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 103 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian bullseye/non-free amd64 nvidia-openjdk-8-jre amd64 9.+8u332-ga-1~~deb9u1~11.2.2-3+deb11u3 [28.1 MB]
Fetched 28.1 MB in 16s (1,783 kB/s)                                            
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-openjdk-8-jre.
(Reading database ... 189063 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-openjdk-8-jre_9.+8u332-ga-1~~deb9u1~11.2.2-3+deb11u3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-openjdk-8-jre (9.+8u332-ga-1~~deb9u1~11.2.2-3+deb11u3) ...
Setting up nvidia-openjdk-8-jre (9.+8u332-ga-1~~deb9u1~11.2.2-3+deb11u3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u6) ...
```

But when I list Java versions there are no Java 8:

```
$ update-alternatives --list java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

How can I install Java 8?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

1. Download x64 RPM packet from [java website](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp)
2. Run `sudo apt install alien`
3. Run `cd {path_to_rpm_file_dir}`
4. Run `alien {rpm_file_name}`
5. Run `sudo apt install ./{name_of_generated_deb_file}`
   Then try to run `update-alternatives --list java` again